# Block.One are not starting the EOSIO blockchain, so who will be?

Tags: tokens, blockchains, esoio

In the latest [community announcement](https://block.one/eosio-1-0-release-update), Block.one have sent a reminder that they will not be launching any of the initial EOSIO blockchains, and warning us not to share our private keys with untrusted apps.

Further:

> It is up to others to adopt and implement the open source EOSIO
>   software Block.one develops. As such, there is no assurance or
>   guarantee that any EOS ERC-20 tokens can be transferred or otherwise
>   exchanged for tokens on any new EOSIO blockchain.

Presumably however, some third parties are planning to actually implement blockchains based on EOSIO, and allow transfer of our ERC-20 tokens.

What seems to be emerging as the most trusted EOSIO based platform(s) in the EOS community that we will be able to transfer our tokens to?

Comment: Very good question! I'm also interested to know what's the reason behind this reversal and when was it established; they call it a "reminder" but for me it's the first time I hear about it and I've been following the announcements coming over from block.one

Finally, I'd be interested to find a forum to discuss this with the community - are there any reddit or steam threads about this?

Comment: There is an 'unofficial' EOS Community Forum which can be found here: https://eosforum.org, might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Vroomfundel To be fair, I first bought EOS during the first 5 day period of the distrubution, and I do remember reading that Block.one were developing the code for EOSIO only, and that it would be up to third party block producers to form the actual blockchain. It is just that I didn't fully comprehend what that meant all the time. Now we are getting closer to the launch, I feel the time has come to understand it a bit better...

Comment: @Vroomfundel - this is not a new position. block.one have been clear about this from the start, but it's not immediately obvious from the whitepaper. It is much more explicit in the EOS faq: https://eos.io/faq

Comment: OK, it seems that I've missed the memo on this. It freaked out at first as I thought it's a new development and now developers should scramble to build chains in the remaining few weeks. I'm still not entirely relieved though as we need at least 21 credible block producers and I have come across just one so far.

Comment: Don't panic, other than eosDAC, I've seen quite a few. For example BuildTeam: https://steemit.com/eos/@buildteam/buildteam-eos-block-producer-candidacy-announcement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a post outlining a hypothetical example of how the chain will be launched written by the VP of Product at block.one:

https://medium.com/@thomas.cox_39839/magic-15-unlocking-the-eosio-blockchain-91ec54f7b48d

In the post Thomas walks through a hypothetical main net release whereby "a self-selected group of Block Producer candidates" start up a chain.  Essentially what will happen is there will be an initial bios boot node that takes a snapshot of the initial token distribution as well as the initial block producers.  These initial block producers will then verify that the snapshot hash, as well as the system contracts (these will be used for voting) are correct.  If they are, they'll begin to create blocks, which will include votes for new BPs.  However, no one will be able to transfer tokens until 15% of token holders sign a transaction on the net, this is essentially a "vote" for this particular block chain by the community.

As requested, here's a recent list of BP candidates by EOSGO:
https://steemit.com/eos/@eosgo/block-producer-candidate-report-9-may-16-2018

Here's a bitcointalk post with a list of BP candidates and a map showing geographically where these BP candidates exist in the world:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3317424.0

Finally, this eosgo forum has a lot of information related to BP candidacy, with numerous candidates announcing their candidacy (team members, location, hardware specs, etc) so you can get an idea of what it takes, and who you'd like to vote for:
https://forums.eosgo.io/categories/block-producer-discussion

Comment: In StackExchange it is considered good form to summarize the answer from an external link, incase it becomes broken in future.

Comment: This was an enlightening read but it still leaves a lot unanswered. How do we review and appraise the BP candidates? Do we even have 21+ solid ones? How do we vote?

Comment: You'll be able to tell a BP is bad by the fact that the network isn't functioning as expected.  There is a list somewhere of current BP candidates, I'll see if I can find the link later today.  You vote using the eosio.system contract which will be verified by all BPs (see the summary of the post above)

Comment: +1. I will mark this answer as accepted if you make one final edit with the list of block producers (or multiple lists, I know of at least two, one by eosgo and another on eosindex).

Answer (score 1):

Oh mate, quite how our two worlds have not collided is a bit of a mystery to me but let me introduce you to the world of Block Producer Candidates!

Please do not panic because at the moment myself, being the Lead Candidate here at eosuk.io , and teams like mine all over the world are preparing for the launch of the EOS Blockchain two weeks from now when the Freeze command becomes available. I can assure you we are all eating, sleeping, breathing and dreaming about EOS Block Production at the moment and if you pop onto Telegram you will find multiple EOS Block Producer groups. Like 1 for bios boot, one for the launch, one for governance, one for testnets, etc, etc, etc. There is a LOT going on at the moment.

Probably the single very best place to go to start learning about the Global Block Producer Election that is going to be an ever-present part of the EOS network is the latest Block Producer Candidate Report #9 which lists all 147 Candidates(at the time of writing, but new candidates are declaring every day) and can be seen at https://steemit.com/eos/@eosgo/block-producer-candidate-report-9-may-16-2018

The Block Producer Candidates are going to launch the EOS network from a snapshot of the Ethereum Blockchain taken after the Freeze command is run. Once the network has settled in each EOS token holder can vote for 30 Block Producers who they believe are capable of running the network (please give 1 vote for EOS UK! :-) ) and the 21 BPs with the most votes will begin producing blocks.

Each round of Block Production will be performed by the top 21 BPs and the vote is ongoing, so in theory the top 21 could change every 1 minute and 3 seconds! Each BP will write 6 blocks at half second intervals so that's 3 seconds x 21 BPs = 1 minute and 3 seconds per round. However, I have seen different calculations for this so I might be wrong about the exact time for a round but its around that. (on the testnet we are writing 9 blocks each per round I think)

Note that the initial EOS network will be launched by BP Candidates at their own cost and we will not be earning Block Rewards until constitution zero has been accepted which may take up to 30 days after the launch. In fact the BPs that launch the network may not get enough votes to become Elected Block Producers, so it is a fairly bizarre scenario where the people who enable the voting system may not get voted in, but we are all agreeing to do it for the good of the network and to get it launched.

Here is a link the EOS Go Block Producer Portal which is meant to be listing all the BPs (although for some reason we are not showing on the map, only our events, Sad Face, but I'll share the link anyway, because that's the way we roll in the EOS Community, we're all really nice, Happy Face!)
https://bp.eosgo.io/explore/

Comment: "quite how our two worlds have not collided is a bit of a mystery" In truth, it is probably because I've been keeping a fairly low profile as a kind of hermit in the Highlands of Scotland.